# How does Jmeter thread group loop works

Tags: performance, jmeter

Recently start learning Jmeter. I noticed that when I set thread group as:

threads: 2,

ramp-up: 10 seconds,

loops: 5.

Part1: it takes 1~5 sec to run the first thread, part2: 6-10sec to run 2nd thread.
And during part1, it loops and sends 5 requests, part2 the same.

My question one is: during each loop, are the 5 requests being sent one after another, and will only start after the previous one is fully finished?

In above example there are plenty of time for each thread to loop. But what will be like if the time is not enough to finish the loop before next thread start:

if threads: 2,

ramp-up: 10 secs,

loops: 500.

Let's say in first 5 seconds the server cannot finish 500 requests, and from sec 6 the thread2 starts. So there will be active requests from both part1 and part2 running at the same time.

Question 2 I'd assume, as within the loop it's sending one after another done, so there will always be 2 active requests (each 1 from 2 threads). By this way it has approximate 500 times of 2 concurrent threads. Is this understanding correct?

Does the above understanding sound correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter starts all threads according to what you set in [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period).

2 threads and 10 seconds ramp-up means that after 10 seconds you will have 2 threads up and running, JMeter will start 1 thread in 5 seconds.

Once started the thread begins executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

When thread executes last sampler it starts the new iteration immediately. When there are no more samplers to execute and loops to iterate the thread is being shut down.

When there are no more running threads the test ends.

Threads are absolutely independent. Each thread waits for the previous sampler to finish before starting the next sampler. Thread starts next iteration when the last sampler is executed, the other thread can still be running the previous iteration. If you want all of them to complete everything before starting the next iteration take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)